# cannot connect to genymotion and getting proxy error

Tags: authentication, proxy, genymotion

I have dowloaded latest version of genymotion with proxy server 2.2.2 and while connecting i am getting invalid reply from server (do you use a proxy?). I am not using proxy for sure. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996772/genymotion-proxy-with-user-password)

Answer (score 1):

Answer, its all about the http proxy server on the genymotion settings just UNCHECK on the genymotion setting or remover the http proxy server by UN-ticking the ability to enter HTTP PROXY and PORT let it be blank by unckecking hence login your credentials, if it doesn't work try confirming you email with genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I went to Settings > Network > I checked "Use HTTP Proxy" and I filled the Http Proxy and port fields (with company proxy valid values). 
After that I connect smoothly as silk.

Comment: Can you give me more info about filling the Http Proxy and prof fields?

Comment: Depends on your OS and genymotion versions the step-by-step procedure may differ. You need to ask proxy address and port (for http and https) to your company or who else manages the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in ubuntu and after some struggle when i was almost giving up i stop the docker (had one instance running in port 3337 in my PC) and for my surprise it's finally work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a **similar issue** (invalid reply from server without Proxy, on a highly customized and quite broken ubuntu 16.04). **nothing of the above helped**. (seemingly)

Then I visited this site:

http://qaru.site/questions/835901/genymotion-stuck-on-splash-screen

(well, you have to let google translate it, if you are not russian)

**the error described there is completely different**. (computer crash resulting in different networking issues)

but it had one thing in common with my case:

everything worked fine, and then **suddenly: SOME NETWORKING ERROR - without reason**

well, for me, the solution was the same as described on the russian page:

**removing** **a** (corrupted?!) **conf file**.

the conf file was at (my home folder)/**.config/Genymobile/Genymotion.conf**

i deleted it (i had to do it with root, because the file was owned by root, but this might have been the case because i messed a bit with genymotion...)

Then, i **restarted genymotion and logged in again** and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had to allow Genymtion.exe in windows firewall. I'm using v3

Answer (score -4):

Had the same problem, managed it using a VPN.

Comment: A better version of this answer would explain why using a VPN fixes the issue the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @Xirema sorry for that, but i don't know why even this problem exists, i just try it out and it worked!