# Running Genymotion/MEmu on a proxy

Tags: android, linux, windows, proxy, bluestacks

I am at a place where there is a proxy server along with username/password authentication.
Apps like MEmu/bluestacks/Genymotion cannot run on proxy so i googled and found some ways to work around this problem - ( before i start i gotta tell that i use both Windows10 and Linux Mint so any workaround for my problem for both platforms would be much appreciated)

1. using an app which tunnels the whole virtual device through the proxy.

-----(a) Proxy Droid - i used this app whith the HTTP authentication and proxy and it works well with the browser and google play store but it fails to run some apps like youtube, clashofclans etc.

-----(b) Psiphon - i generally use this app on my mobile phone and it works for all of the apps by routing the device through a Socksv5 proxy, BUT it crashes when i run it on on android emulators. Psiphon connects and simply crashes the whole device in genymotion/MEmu.

-----(c) Drony - this app is for those who don't have super user priviliges (or simply a phone without root) . It has the option to force user-selected apps  to run behind a proxy by linking and passing the traffic through ORBOT, sadly my internet provider has blocked Tor's services and it fails to connect . ( the browser and google play store work in it but CoC and youtube don't)

2. So in google i found posts related to setting proxy using the advanced options in wifi options, but sadly it works only with the browser.( [Genymotion proxy with user/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996772/genymotion-proxy-with-user-password) )
3. i also tried using CCproxy and psiphon3.exe to tunnel my whole pc but it doesn't make MEmu/Bluestacks go through that socksv5 connection.
4. i have set up my apt.conf file in linux ( alongwith the proxy and authentication) but it too gives only the terminal and software manager access to the internet  but fails to do so for Genymotion. i have manually setup proxy in Genymotion ( again thanks to - [Genymotion proxy with user/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996772/genymotion-proxy-with-user-password)).

......... blah-blah

So ppl help me out please and thanks in advance to anyone who finds a solution XD .

and p.s - if anyone wants any snapshot / anything else that might include some work on my part , just tell me so and i'll be ready to help

cheers - Prakhar Sharma

Comment: Hello Prakhar Sharma, I am in a similar bunch and curious if you ever figured out how to run a proxy through Memu or any other emulator where it will work for apps like youtube zillow . . .etc thankyou and hope to hear back.

Answer (score 1):

for bluestack I can recommend proxycap, after you add the proxy create a rule to route true the .exe you specified

Comment: It actually does answer the question. Using proxycap solves the problem described by OP. The solution could be better worded, but it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found Shadowsocks for android.
I'm running the emulator "Memu" on Windows 10, i have a proxyserver in my Network and it works very well.

Install "Shadowsocks" from Google Play Store on your emulator, connect with the default setting, minimize it and start the app/game that you want to use with.

Comment: hi.. im trying shadowshocks but there are no username to in config to setup connection to sock